# Recursion memorisation approach to stamp problem

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

**Context:**
We have stamps available in various denominations like 1,5,66,85,100.
Suppose that we have an unlimited number of stamps of each denomination available, and we want to make a certain value, say 138, with the minimum possible number of stamps.
On the one hand we could have

138 = 100+5+5+5+5+5+5+5+1+1+1 (11 stamps),

but it's best to use

138 = 66+66+5+1 (4 stamps).

The question is to make a function `min_stamps(x,den)`  that returns the minimum number of stamps needed to make the amount `x`, where `den` is a tuple of the available denominations of stamps. We assume that all amounts are postive integers, and that `den` includes `1`, which guarantees that it is possible to make every amount.

We have been asked to use a recursion memorisation approach on the question. My attempt is below.

```
def min_stamps(x,den):
    global MEMO
    if (x,den) not in MEMO:
        exc = min_stamps(x, den[:-1])
        if den[-1] > x:
            MEMO[(x,den)] = exc
        else:
            inc = min_stamps(x-den[-1], den[:-1])
            MEMO[(x,den)] = min(inc,exc)
    return MEMO[(x,den)]
```

When using the function above on `min_stamps(138,(1,5,66,85,100))` I get `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. I expect to get 4 from this value-denomination pair, but I'm not sure how to fix this and I'm not sure if my logic in the code above for tackling the question is entirely correct.

Comment: There is no base case to stop the recursion

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your logic is wrong.

My guess is, the reason you're getting infinite recursion is because of this

```py
exc = min_stamps(x, den[:-1])
```

Your code will never pass this line. The first execution, `den=(1,5,66,85,100)`, after that `den=(1,5,66,85)`, after that `den=(1,5,66,85)` `....` till its empty right? But even when it's empty, `den[-1]` will still be `()`, hence infinite recursion.
Also I think your whole code is just plain wrong, I don't think I really understand it.

Secondly, there's no base case to terminate the recursion.

Here's how I would've written the code

```py
def f(x, den) :
 global mem
 # memoization
 if x in mem: return mem[x]
 # base case, when the value is one of the stamps, there's exactly one way to make it
 elif x in den: return 1
 # prevents negative values from being counted
 elif x<0: return float("inf")
 # the main logic
 else:
  mem[x] = float("inf")
  for stamp on den:
   mem[x] = min(mem[x], f(x-stamp, den) +1) 
  return mem[x]
```

This works because, the minimum number of ways would involve subtrscting the value of any of the stamps from the number. We add 1 cause that's value for using one stamp. Do this recursively and memoize, you have your standard dynamic programming problem